# What strikes me the most - usage

Tags: word-usage, sentence

Can anyone explain what does this mean and how to use it correctly in a sentence?

> What strikes me the most

Comment: What strikes me the most is why you didn't include your own research efforts in your question.

Comment: The meaning of the phrase is simply "what is most apparent or evident to me."

Comment: Welcome to English Language & Usage. **Questions that can be answered using [commonly-available references](http://meta.english.stackexchange.com/questions/2573/what-good-reference-works-on-english-are-available) are off-topic**. Please make sure you take the [tour](http://english.stackexchange.com/tour) and visit our [help center](http://english.stackexchange.com/help) for additional guidance.

Comment: @SvenYargs thank you for taking my question seriously and answering it.

Comment: @Rathony I have done my own research before posting the question but I did not find the result accurate enough or satisfying.

Comment: To [strike](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/strike): 3. (Of a thought or idea) come into the mind of (someone) suddenly or unexpectedly. 3.1 Cause (someone) to have a particular impression: , 3.2:  (be struck by/with) Find particularly interesting, noticeable, or impressive:

Comment: @MK "What strikes me 'most'" is a more common idiom... https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=strikes+me+most+is%2Cstrikes+me+the+most+is&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=17&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cstrikes%20me%20most%20is%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cstrikes%20me%20the%20most%20is%3B%2Cc0; https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=strikes+me+most+about%2Cstrikes+me+the+most+about&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=17&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cstrikes%20me%20most%20about%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cstrikes%20me%20the%20most%20about%3B%2Cc0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The phrase is used when a person has several thoughts and opinions, all valid, about something that has happened and wants to say what, for him, seems most important. It is particularly used when the most important thought is not the most obvious, or not the one that other people in the conversation have noticed.

> I have read her letter and what strikes me the most about it is that she didn't even mention the problems with her husband.

This is not the most obvious thing about the letter, as it isn't even in it, but to the speaker what has been left out is actually more significant.

> A group of people may be discussing changes to the government's agricultural policies, focussing mainly on cucumbers. Someone else may then say: "What strikes me the most about the changes is the abolition of cabbage tax."

He is saying that, to him, there is something more significant than the effect on cucumbers, which the others have not noticed. To him, the effect on cabbages is more important.